# How applications like Global Mapper, ArcMap and ArcScene support showing high resolution geotiff images?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, c++, performance, image-pyramids

Considering my question in Game Developement:

[How to create textures of big images in opengl (bigger than the MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61436/how-to-create-textures-of-big-images-in-opengl-bigger-than-the-max-texture-size)

it seems that, there's no way to show an image bigger than the MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE in OpenGL (I'm not sure yet, looking forward to more answers in Game Developement)

In my case MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 8192 but my image is a 16997x15931 which can be shown in openGL based on my current knowledge about this API.

Just tobe curious, and maybe they're using a toolkit or API which is not free

**What way programs like Global Mapper, ArcMap and ArcScene manage to show high resolution geotiff images for example bigger than 15000x15000 with high performance?**

**What toolkit, API, 3rd party library do they use for `display tasks` and `2D or 3D rendering` in their programs?**

I highly doubt that image-pyramids is the concept related to my question?
if it's true beyond answering my question about APIs please introduce me a link in GDAL documentation that has an excellent tutorial about pyramids?

Answer (score 2):

The concept is tiling whether in game or in display or in Image. You don't need the higher resolution because you display wouldn't show it and you would waste the rendering hit to your cpu and graphics card. You use lower resolution at greater distances with a tile mosaic but even up close would never need 16997x15931. textures in games are tiled but tiles in GIS aren't for texturing so that is the intellectual inconsistency. Both, however are for the purpose of reducing rendering costs through generalizing image data and would be a 1x1 ratio, not screen display.

Comment: So thanks @lewis you say such programs use tiling. Do you know if tiling is supported in OpenGL? I don't think so. I'm forced to do my project with openGL. So maybe you mean multiple texturing in opengl?